# Creating a Visual Studio 2013 extension that hosts PowerShell

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-extensions

Much of my build process is a collection of PowerShell scripts and functions, all defined within a `.ps1` file.  I simply have a shortcut to that file on my desktop, and it launches PowerShell and initializes everything.

Now, I think it would be handy if I could just run that shell *within* the Visual Studio 2013 environment.  That way, I wouldn't need to keep switching windows when I want to build, publish things to IIS, perform database provisioning, etc.  Should be easy enough, right?

The first thing I found was [PowerConsole](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/67620d8c-93dd-4e57-aa86-c9404acbd7b3), an extension for Visual Studio that allows users to access Power Shell from within VS.  However, it only works with Visual Studio 2010.  [According to the author](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/67620d8c-93dd-4e57-aa86-c9404acbd7b3/view/Discussions#5953), the NuGet team basically forked his code and it's now part of the NuGet console.  So, my next idea was to just use the NuGet console.  This has a few problems:

1. It's called the "Package Manager Console" and hidden away in some menu.  I want something easy to get to and clear that it's a build environment for my product.
2. While you can run PowerShell commands such as `dir`, it doesn't really behave like PowerShell.  For example, you can't change the prompt, even if you override the `prompt` function.
3. There doesn't seem to be a way to override the profile.  When I run my `BuildShell.ps1` file, none of the functions within the file are registered and nothing seems to change.

Overall, this seems like a hacky way to integrate a custom build environment into Visual Studio.  So, next step is to create my own extension.  After all, that's all NuGet is, right?

**The Question:**

How do you create a *NuGet* like extension for Visual Studio 2013?  MSDN has quite a few [Visual Studio 2013 Extension samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb458154.aspx), however they seem to be geared around extending the editor (such as what reSharper might do) and not creating new command windows.  I'm looking for something to get me started, or perhaps an open source program I can look at.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered [PowerShell Tools for Visual Studio](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c9eb3ba8-0c59-4944-9a62-6eee37294597)?

Comment: This appears to be an extension to edit and debug `.ps1` scripts.  Does it also let you host PowerShell within Visual Studio?

Comment: Just so I am clear here, you are just wanting the shell present within the editor right?  You are not seeking to connect an application to the runspace, right?

Comment: Basically I want `PowerShell.exe` within a window in Visual Studio.  I want to be able to run `.ps1` files, create new functions, change directories, and everything else I can do in PowerShell.exe.

Comment: I have worked with the PowerShell Tools for VS, but it does not give you a shell window.  I have a web service I reference for executing some powershell script in a C# app, but that is done once and I move on.  Typically, I just use PowerGui and the shell window for editing.

I did just add a new external tool, but all that does it add a link for launch PowerShell.  Hardly what you are wanting.

Comment: Power Console is *close* to what I want.  However, it doesn't appear you can change the prompt or create profiles (like scripts that run automatically when it starts).  Plus, it only works with VS2010.  I'd love to get my hands on the Power Console source code.